# If $f$ is continuous on $(-π,π]$ then its Fourier series converges pointwise to $f$ on every $x$ for which $f$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

The title of this question is stated as a theorem in Abbott's Understanding Analysis book, in the additional topics chapter covering Fourier series, in which he gives a very brief introduction into this topic (for instance, I don't know anything about Lebesgue integration or any other condition which I saw have been mentioned in some answers regarding Fourier series). Abbott starts his proof by considering the $n-th$ partial sum of the Fourier series:
$$S_N(x,f)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^N a_ncos(nx)+b_nsin(nx) $$
And he aims to prove that: $\lim_{N \to \infty}S_N(x,f)=f(x)$ pointwise for all $x$ for which $f'(x)$ exists.
After some manipulations involgin the Dirichlet Kernel he arrives at writing:
$$S_N(x,f)-f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi [f(t+x)-f(x)]D_N(t)dt$$
Where $D_N(t)$ is the Dirichlet Kernel, which Abbott previously defined as: $$\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^Ncos(kt)$$ and then he proved that for $t\in R$ different from $2k\pi$, where $k$ is any integer,     $D_N(t)$ can be written as:
$$\frac{sin[(N+1/2)t]}{2sin(t/2)}$$
He then uses the identity:
$$D_N(t)=\frac{sin[(N+1/2)t]}{2sin(t/2)}=\frac{sin(Nt)cos(t/2)}{2sin(t/2)}+\frac{cos(Nt)}{2}$$,to split the integral written before as:
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{p_x(t)sin(Nt)}{2\pi}dt+\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{q_x(t)cos(Nt)}{2\pi}dt$$
Where: $$p_x(t)=\frac{[f(t+x)-f(x)]cos(t/2)}{sin(t/2)}$$
$$q_x(t)=[f(t+x)-f(x)]$$
And here is my first problem with this proof: he managed to split this integral in two by using the sine addition formula on $D_N(t)$, but he does this in an integral on $[-\pi,\pi]$, which covers the point $0$, for which $D_N(t)$ IS NOT equal to the ratio of sines. I think it might be something that could be solved by using a limit argument on the integration bounds around $0$, so that then you can substitute the $D_N(t)$ with the ratio of sines, so I tried this (splitting the very first integral in two, one on $[-\pi,-\epsilon]$ and the other on $[\epsilon,\pi]$, then taking a limit as $\epsilon$ approaches $0$, so that I could write $D_N(t)$ as a ratio of sines, but I wasn't able to go on with this process, if anyone has some hints on how to proceed, please let me know)
I eventually continued to read the proof, which "ends" giving the reader an exercise in which you have to show that on both integral it can be used the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, which would finish the proof.
On the second integral:
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{q_x(t)cos(Nt)}{2\pi}dt$$
is quite easy to notice that $q_x(t)$ is continuos, being the difference of continous function, and thus the Riemman-Lebegue lemma makes us able to write:
$$\lim_{N \to \infty}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{q_x(t)cos(Nt)}{2\pi}dt=0$$
The problem comes when I have to prove that $p_x(t)$ is continuous at $0$. It's not hard to notice that, since $f$ is differentiable at $x$ we can write:
$$\lim_{t \to 0} p_x(t)=2f'(x)$$
And this is fine, but I still don't get how this helps us to say why $p_x(t)$ is continuous at $0$, since this function is not defined at that point. After some time i decide to look up on the solution manual and I read his solution, which is this:

> The fact that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and the well know limit $\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{sin(\theta)}{\theta}$=1 imply
> $$\lim_{t \to 0} p_x(t)=2f'(x)$$
> Thus, defining $p_x(0)=2f'(x)$ makes $p_x(t)$ continuous at $0$, and so on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and it now follows from the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma that:
> $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{p_x(t)sin(Nt)}{2\pi}dt=0 $$

And here is my second problem: Why can we do this? Why can we *decide* that our function has a value at a point for which it is undefined? And do we know that making our function has a value at that point does not change our integral (I mean in a rigorous sense, intuitively changing a finite set of points of an integrable function over a closed interval $[a,b]$ shouldn't change the integral, but in his book, Abbott does not give any proof of this nor mentions this fact, and even if he did, this is a different scenario because we're not *changing* the value of $p_x(t)$ at $t=0$, we are *imposing our function to HAVE one*.
So these are my problems with this proof, if anyone could help me justify these steps that Abbott does, or come up with a different proof I would appreciate it. Please let me know if I have not been clear in some parts so that I can edit the question to fill in more detail.

Comment: I have to say that you both are right, if I were to look up an answer just to find it written like I write my questions, I would be kind of upset. I will put some effort and I will take my time to edit my question, hoping to not do a mess. Sorry for the inconvenience and for my lack of commitment into learn the basics of Mathjax